XML Parser Error in Salesforce AJAX Library When Used in LWC with LWS Enabled
I'm encountering an issue with the Salesforce AJAX library (sforce.js) when using it in a Lightning Web Component (LWC) with Lightning Web Security (LWS) enabled. We used the AJAX library to query and fetch files (content) data from Salesforce but kept running into an XML parser error.
Problem: On debugging, I found that LWS was blocking the request because it identified the script as trying to update the document, which caused Salesforce's internal XML handler to fail.
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

After investigating the root cause, I modified the sforce.js AJAX library to capture the response as text instead of directly parsing the XML. I then used JavaScript's DOMParser to manually convert the text into an XML document. This change successfully bypassed the XML parser error.
Here’s a simplified version of what I did:
let responseText = xhr.responseText; // Capture response as text
let parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlResponse = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "application/xml"); // Parse text to XML

This resolved the issue.
Has anyone experienced something similar when using the Salesforce AJAX library with LWS? Would love to hear your thoughts or alternative approaches!
